# Is it safe to place a (potentially heavy) combo amp on top of a cab?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

I've read [this interesting question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/14719/10060), and it made me wonder. The fact of tilting/raising the speakers is rather obvious to me, however there's one possibility I thought of.

Typical big-stage setup involves either one (angled or flat) 4x12" cab and a guitar head, or two cabs, one on top of the other (then typically the lower one is flat, and the amp resides in the backstage). However, many 2x12" combo amps offer an option to work with their built-in speakers and a separate cab simultaneously.

Would  it be safe to put such a (which would weigh about 30kg, compared to the head weighing around 15) on top of a cab? The problems I was able to imagine are

- A combo is vibrating mechanically way more than a stationary head. Could the vibrations move it so it could potentially fall?
- The combo is heavier, so could it damage the cab itself? Could the added mass dampen or affect the sound of the cab in any way?
- Because of that, the assembly, i.e. putting the amp on top, would be way harder. I've also seen some cabs having holes on the top to hold the above cab in place; I doubt the combo's legs would fit them.
- The angled cab has less space on the top, so I guess only the flat ones (that also should be a bit more durable because of that constructions would be elligible there, I guess.

I think it could be an interesting and rather affordable setup, but there might be other things I'm overlooking.

Comment: And just to add, there's [that thing](http://cdn1.gbase.com/usercontent/gear/2874564/p1_upmejad02_so.jpg), so I guess there are no "too weird" setups.

Comment: Perfectly safe if it's someone else's cab  :-) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your approach would work. If there is a slanted cabinet, you could put it on the side, to get more area for your combo.

The question is if it is worth it. If there are slanted cabinets already (which is the usual setup if only one 4x12 is used), then you will get some sound projected towards your ears. Not as much as you would with the combo on top, but I find it is usually sufficient. Dragging around a combo just for the purpose of this is possibly not the best solution.

Another option would be to buy a 2x12 cabinet to bring to shows. Then you can place it underneath the existing 4x12. This gives you the option of leaving it at home when you don't feel like dragging it with you, or space is scarce.

Comment: Heh, I wouldn't even think to put a cab on the side. That could have a nice side-effect of getting the sound "wider", I guess. Your points make a lot of sense, though.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I've seen people do that to build a stack from two slanted cabs. Doesn't look pretty, and probably isn't the most stable setup, but if it works, it works...

Comment: I've been thinking about it, and I kinda see the appeal of yet another setup. Your suggestion about 212 cab was great, but paired with a combo still! That way you have effectively 4x12 when you stack them (and in this case cab can easily go *on top* of the combo), or you can take just the combo if you don't need full power. And it's way easier to transport than a head + full 4x12 cab. I think I've found the sweet spot :)

Answer (score 2):

On my cabs, and the bottom of a combo, there are plastic corner pieces that are designed to lock into each other,both back to front and sideways.Not originally - I put them on.  Mine hasn't fallen off yet !

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't risk it, unless the amp and cab match(from the same company, etc.). I just but an Egnator Tweaker 15W 112 Combo(great amp), and it's pretty heavy so I would put it next to a cab, unless I had the matching cab from Egnator